# Compare Characters Within a Single Column In R

Tags: r

```
head(df)
   V1          V2 V3 V4 V5 V6  V7  V8  V9  V10 V11
1 1152652 1152652  0  0  2 -9 1 1 2 2 0 0 2 2 1 1
2 1051495 1051495  0  0  2 -9 1 1 2 2 0 0 2 2 1 1
3 1195877 1195877  0  0  2 -9 1 1 2 2 0 0 2 2 1 1
```

This df is about 200,000 rows. I would like to compare the 2 integers within the 8th column. I tried converting. When I used `strsplit()`, the situation became super messy.

E.g., If I take column V8:

```
V8 <- as.character(df$V8)
test <- strsplit(V8, " ")
head(test)

[[1]]
[1] "2" "2"
```

Is there a more elegant want to do this? I am only interested in the 8th column. Thanks so much.

Comment: Not really. Your column contains two characters in a single string - you are going to have to split it in some way before comparing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyr::separate`, you can separate the `V8` column into two columns (i.e., `V8a` and `V8b`):

```
library(tidyr)
df <- separate(df,V8,c("V8a","V8b"))
       V1      V2 V3 V4 V5 V6  V7 V8a V8b  V9 V10 V11
1 1152652 1152652  0  0  2 -9 1 1   2   2 0 0 2 2 1 1
2 1051495 1051495  0  0  2 -9 1 1   2   2 0 0 2 2 1 1
3 1195877 1195877  0  0  2 -9 1 1   2   2 0 0 2 2 1 1
```

Then, you can compare these:

```
is_eq <- df$V8a == df$V8b
##[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1152652L, 1051495L, 1195877L), V2 = c(1152652L, 
1051495L, 1195877L), V3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), V4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), 
    V5 = c(2L, 2L, 2L), V6 = c(-9L, -9L, -9L), V7 = c("1 1", 
    "1 1", "1 1"), V8 = c("2 2", "2 2", "2 2"), V9 = c("0 0", 
    "0 0", "0 0"), V10 = c("2 2", "2 2", "2 2"), V11 = c("1 1", 
    "1 1", "1 1")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", 
"V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
##       V1      V2 V3 V4 V5 V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 V11
##1 1152652 1152652  0  0  2 -9 1 1 2 2 0 0 2 2 1 1
##2 1051495 1051495  0  0  2 -9 1 1 2 2 0 0 2 2 1 1
##3 1195877 1195877  0  0  2 -9 1 1 2 2 0 0 2 2 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to leave an idea which you can handle this task for multiple columns since the data set contains a couple of columns which contain two numbers respectively. I created a simple data below. Here, V1 and V2 contain two numbers. So I wanted to do the number comparison for these columns. The first step is to identify which columns contain two numbers. There should be a space between them. Using this idea, you can identify target columns. In `grep()`, I chose the first row of the data and searched strings containing a space. Then, I picked up column names (i.e., V1 and V2). The second step was to split the target columns with `cSplit()`. Once you split the columns, the numbers turned to be numeric, not character. In the third step, you choose a pair of columns in `lapply()` and do simple calculation. If two numbers are identical, the subtract should return 0. You can use this for a logical check and create a new column called `check`, and you choose the column only. Then, you create a data table with `cbind()`. Finally, you want to update column names with `ind` (i.e., V1 and V2).

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(splitstackshape)

mydf <- data.frame(V1 = c("1 1", "2 3", "3 3"),
                   V2 = c("10 11", "12 12", "13 13"),
                   V3 = 101:103,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#   V1    V2  V3
#1 1 1 10 11 101
#2 2 3 12 12 102
#3 3 3 13 13 103

# Find columns which include two numbers.
mydf[, grepl(pattern = "\\s", x = mydf[1, ])] %>%
colnames -> ind

# Prepare a data set splitting numbers in one column
cSplit(mydf, splitCols = ind, direction = "wide", sep = " ") -> temp

# Choose a pair of columns. Check if the subtraction generates 0.
# If 0, two numbers are identical. If not, they do not match.

lapply(ind, function(i){

    temp[, grep(i, x = names(temp)), with = FALSE] -> foo
    foo[, check  :=  foo[, 1, with = FALSE]- foo[, 2, with = FALSE] == 0]
    foo[, 3, with = FALSE] -> foo
    foo
   }) -> temp

# Create a data table
do.call(cbind, temp) -> out

# Update column names
setnames(out, ind) 

#      V1    V2
#1:  TRUE FALSE
#2: FALSE  TRUE
#3:  TRUE  TRUE
```